# Realm Cocoa setErrorHandler Deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm using Realm Cocoa version 3.13.1, and currenly update to newer version of Realm Cocoa 10.5.0

I'm having difficulties to implement deprecated function, could you help me to give the solution on how to handling the error in newer version of Realm?

The previous version I can use `[RLMSyncManager sharedManager] setErrorHandler` to handle the error but now it said that `No known class method for selector 'sharedManager'`

Here is my method to handle the error:

```
(void)loadAllDataFromDatabaseWithQuery:(NSString *)query
                           tableName:(NSString *)tableName
                           sortByKey:(NSString *)columnName
                           ascending:(BOOL)isAscending
                             success:(void (^)(NSArray *resultArray))success
                             failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

RLMRealm *realm = [[TAPDatabaseManager sharedManager] createRealm];
RLMResults *results = [NSClassFromString(tableName) allObjectsInRealm:realm];

if (![query isEqualToString:@""]) {
    results = [results objectsWhere:query];
}

results = [results distinctResultsUsingKeyPaths:@[columnName]];
results = [results sortedResultsUsingKeyPath:columnName ascending:isAscending];

NSArray *resultArray = [NSArray array];
resultArray = [[TAPDatabaseManager sharedManager] convertRealmResultIntoArray:results];

[[RLMSyncManager sharedManager] setErrorHandler:^(NSError *error, RLMSyncSession *session) {
    // handle error
    failure(error);
}];

success(resultArray);
}
```

I provided the image below:

`[RLMSyncManager sharedManager] setErrorHandler are deprecated]`

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAHYn.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks before

Comment: Are you using Sync (i.e. Realm Cloud) at all? If so, you can access the `syncManager` on the app instance: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/objc/10.4.0/Classes/RLMApp.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMApp(py)syncManager. If you're not using Sync, this functionality doesn't do anything and you can just delete it.

Comment: What kind of errors do you want to handle? Are you still using the older depreciated realm cloud instead of MongoDB Realm?